# update query not performing well when using the joins from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, query-optimization

I have been trying to update the single column from the two tables using the joins as below,

`update skus sk inner join products ss on (sk.id = ss.sk_number) set sk.style_id = (select id from categories where style_number = ss.st_number)`

I have applied indexes also for required fields but here skus table `sk.id` is string type primary key.

products table : sk_number and st_number fields where applied indexes also.

I don't know what is wrong in that query? share me your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**example:**

```
UPDATE A    
  SET ControllingSalesRep = RA.SalesRepCode   
from DHE.dbo.tblAccounts A
  INNER JOIN DHE_Import.dbo.tblSalesRepsAccountsLink RA
    ON A.AccountCode = RA.AccountCode
```

**your query:**

```
update sk set sk.style_id = (select id from categories where style_number = ss.st_number) from skus sk inner join products ss on (sk.id = ss.sk_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  ...

```
update sk set sk.style_id = ca.id from categories ca  inner join products ss  on ca.style_number = ss.st_number inner join skus sk  on (sk.id = ss.sk_number)
```